# Select specific elements from a dictionary with tuple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the values are tuples. 
The structure is something like this:

```
my_dictionary = {'class1': (5, 10, 15, 20), 'class2': (1, 2, 3, 4), 'class3': (10, 20, 30, 40)}
```

Now I want to loop over the dictionary keys and take a specific element from the tuple of values, so say I want to get the first tuple element of each class. How to do that?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for `dict.values`:

```
>>> [t[0] for t in my_dictionary.values()]
[5, 1, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also unpack the first item from each tuple in `my_dictionary.values()`:

```
>>> [x for x, *_ in my_dictionary.values()]
[5, 1, 10]
```

Or use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to select the first item:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(map(itemgetter(0), my_dictionary.values()))
[5, 1, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Now I want to loop over the dictionary keys and take a specific element from the tuple of values*

```py
print(*(my_dictionary[i][0] for i in my_dictionary)) #5 1 10
```

As asked:

- loops over keys
- takes the mentioned index value of the tuple for every class

#### Code Profile

- Takes 88 bytes and 275ns for a 1000 key/value pairs

Why is it so memory efficient?

- Because of the use of generators.

[image: code profile]